# Tag Map-Biology-SE

Tags: discussion

This seems pretty cool

https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/tag-map-for-crossvalidated

Our brothers at Chem.SE have something of the sort
https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/57

Comment: I'm sorry if I seem a bit dense, but are you asking if Bio.SE can do something similar? I guess I wasn't able to follow what question you're asking here. If so, that would be a pretty cool thing do see!

Comment: Well the code is posted [here](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/blob/master/README.md) and it doesn't look too difficult to do, I'll give it a go on Friday if no one beats me to it!

Comment: @RoryM You'll need to ping me in TL for some help, I assure you.

Comment: @Aarthi ahh, that's be being an optimist is it, will do ;)

Comment: @RoryM Just in case, if the recipe was not clear, just let me know. I will try to polish it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, here it is for Biology.SE:

[image]

Some more description e.g. on [a respective post on meta.math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/a-graph-map-of-math-se). In particular, colours stand for graph communities (groups of nodes which have a lot of connections between each other).

The project is on GitHub: https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki (feel invited to tweak the plot to your taste).

I hope you like it! :)

## EDIT

A newer, interactive and always up-to-date version is here: [**TagOverflow**](http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/?site=biology&size=32).

[Code and a more detailed description is on GitHub](https://github.com/stared/tagoverflow#tagoverflow).

[image]

Comment: @mods: what happened here? The pic now looks like sort of gaming interface to me.

Comment: @dd3 I fixed it. No idea why it got changed (perhaps a problem with the picture server).

Comment: [Here is a 2017 update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5gQq.png) I created using tagOverflow. Just to capture how things have changed...

Comment: @theforestecologist Feel invited to post it, with a screenshot. :)

Answer (score 3):

For fun, here's the updated January 5, 2017 Update:

[image: Tag Map-Biology-SE - 2017]

I tried to arrange the dots in a way that mirrored Piotr's [2015 update](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/371/16866).

Unsurprisingly, there is minimal change.

Answer (score 2):

Here is manually-done one. Each color indicate a highly related field of study.

[image: Map]

Comment: Nice. care to share the methodology and/or program you used to do this?

Comment: @theforestecologist MS-Paint and common sense

Comment: @theforestecologist Thank you for your appreciation.